# How to execute Javascript in ASPNET JavaScriptServices (Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, asp.net-core-2.0

I am porting an application from ASP.NET Framework 4.6 to .NET Core 2 and trying to replicate the features I had with Microsoft ClearScript.V8. I looked for NodeJS and ReactJS but they seem to be a bit overkill and missing the features I am looking for. I don't need to get a rendering result but I need to be able to inject objects that represent variables and updating the value of one variable needs to call back-end so I can update its value in database.

I also need to be able to restrict the time the script can run. I am setting a 3 second timeout so that a user cannot hang a thread with an infinite loop or code that would run for too long.

With ClearScript.V8 in Framework 4.6 I have code like:

```
using Microsoft.ClearScript;
using Microsoft.ClearScript.V8;

using (SmartScript script = new SmartScript())
{
   dynamic addSmartPropertyBool = GetSmartProperty(script._engine, "boolean", true);

   engine.AddHostObject("_ImSmart", script);
   var smartVariableBool = new SmartBoolean(UserId, VariableName, false);
   addSmartPropertyBool(script._engine.Script, VariableName, smartVariableBool);

   script._engine.TimedEvaluate(Constants.DefaultScriptTimeout, someCode);
}

public dynamic GetSmartProperty(ScriptEngine engine, string type, Boolean readOnly)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case "boolean":
            if (readOnly)
                return engine.Evaluate(@"
                        (function (obj, name, smartBoolean) {
                            Object.defineProperty(obj, name, {
                                enumerable: true,
                                get: function () { return smartBoolean.value; }
                            });
                        })
                    ");
            else
                return engine.Evaluate(@"
                        (function (obj, name, smartBoolean) {
                            Object.defineProperty(obj, name, {
                                enumerable: true,
                                get: function () { return smartBoolean.value; },
                                set: function (value) { smartBoolean.value = value; }
                            });
                        })
                    ");
    }

    return null;
}

public class SmartScript : IDisposable
{
    private Guid _userId;
    public ScriptEngine _engine;

    public SmartScript(Guid userId)
    {
        _userId = userId;
        _engine = new V8ScriptEngine();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _engine.Dispose();
    }
}

public class SmartBoolean : ISmartVariable
{
    private Guid UserId;
    private string Name;
    public string type
    {
        get {
            return "boolean";
        }
    }
    private Boolean _value;
    public Boolean value
    {
        get {
            return _value;
        }

        set {
            _value = value;

            if (value)
                new SmartCommon().SetTrue(Name);  // Set value in DB
            else
                new SmartCommon().SetFalse(Name);  // Set value in DB
        }
    }

    public SmartBoolean(Guid UserId, string Name, Boolean value)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this._value = value;
        this.UserId = UserId;
    }
}
```

I left some code out for simplicity but I am looking for the following functionalities:

- Inject variables in Javascript engine.
- Updating a variable in Javascript code will call back-end so I can update the value in database.
- Ability to restrict execution runtime.

How can I achieve this with JavascriptServices in .NET Core 2? Or any other engine that would allow these functionalities.

Comment: What did you end up going with? I'm going through a similar evaluation of what is the best javascript scripting engine for .NET Core.

Comment: @deandob I ended up splitting my app in two: interface in Core and scripting in Framework 4.6. Interface communicates with scripting through a web API. There is a small overhead but, in my case, it’s very manageable.

Comment: OK thanks. I need Linux and ARM support for my app so this looks like it narrows the field considerably.